# Why is Node hanging on exit of this script with lots of chained Promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, garbage-collection

I was prototyping a script to be used for testing purposes that will sequentially fire a fair number of http requests and will continue despite any errors along the way.  (Also, this was a nifty way to play with deep recursion without overflowing the call stack.)

Basically, each callback function creates another promise to add to the chain until it runs out of items to process.  In the case of this prototype, no actual processing is done.  It just rejects each value immediately.  However, when my script is done, Node will just hang there for a while maxing out a processor core.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const requests = [...Array(100000).keys()];

const rejection = arg => new Promise((_, reject) => reject(arg));

function handleFailureAndContinue() {
  if (requests.length > 0) {
    return rejection(requests.pop())
      .then(undefined, handleFailureAndContinue);
  } else {
    console.log('finish: ' + new Date().toISOString());
  }
}

console.log('start:  ' + new Date().toISOString());

rejection(requests.pop())
  .then(undefined, handleFailureAndContinue);
```

To figure out how large the array has to be before it starts showing this behavior, I started with 10 and grew by an order of magnitude until I could observe the odd behavior.  For my laptop, I started noticing it at 100000.

Then, I ran this command to time it and see how long the actual code took to run and how long Node was spinning until it exited.

```
# This was on a Mac, so you'll want to use date instead of gdate on Linux.
./promiseTest.js && printf "exit:   " && TZ=Zulu gdate -Ins
```

Here were the results.

```
start:  2018-12-11T23:49:06.282Z
finish: 2018-12-11T23:49:06.396Z
exit:   2018-12-11T23:50:00,370138000+00:00
```

As you can see, the code itself took less than a second to execute, but Node then did something for almost a minute before exiting.  If I had to guess, I'd say there was probably a bunch of garbage collection going on, but I don't know that for certain.

**How can I figure out why this is happening and how can I avoid it?**

Comment: You can run node inside chrome's debugger,.  You can then inspect the heap & garbage collection etc.  Just run node with the `--inspect` option.. eg.. `node --inspect index`, then open chrome and place this in the URL,  `chrome://inspect`, you then have the full power of chromes debugger.

Comment: ps.  if you also want node to pause until debugger is attached, also pass `--inspect-brk`

Comment: probably a failure in nodejs Promise implementation ... since using bluebird (or most any other Promise library) instead of "native" fixes the issue

Comment: Thanks, @JaromandaX.  I think I'll escalate this to the nodejs/help repo in that case.

Comment: For those following along, I opened a ticket: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/25000

Answer (score 0):

I think node did not receive a signal that the chain was complete, the script then exists when node times out. A couple of things:

1. Remove the '_' parameter from the Promise function call
2. Remove undefined as a parameter from the `.then()` functions
3. Add a return in the else clause of the `handleFailureAndContinue()` so the function is always closing and not hanging the thenable chain.
4. Add a catch to the initial `rejection()` call

Revise the code to:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env node
    const requests = [...Array(100000).keys()];

    const rejection = arg => new Promise((reject) => reject(arg));

    function handleFailureAndContinue() {
      if (requests.length > 0) {
        return rejection(requests.pop())
          .then(handleFailureAndContinue);
      } else {
        console.log('finish: ' + new Date().toISOString());
        return
      }
    }

    console.log('start:  ' + new Date().toISOString());

    rejection(requests.pop())
     .then(handleFailureAndContinue)
     .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Comment: The timeout explanation doesn't explain why node doesn't hang when there are fewer items in `requests`.  Also, this completely changes the dynamics of what's going on in the original code.  I don't want a failure in the chain to stop execution, which is what will happen in your code.  I was specifically testing promise rejection.